# Company not prepared for interview

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, hiring

I was recently invited to a phone interview at a company who seemed to have interesting projects. This is for a permanent senior developer role. I was told it would be an hour long session with two company staff.

At the appointed time I did not receive a call. After 15 minutes I contacted the recruiter to check if he had passed the correct contact details. He seemed surprised and called me back in a couple of minutes to say they had in 'incident' and had forgotten to call me and would call me now.

I spoke to the hiring manager who explained that due to an unexpected meeting everyone was busy and he would do a quick 10 minute session.

I was later invited for a face-to-face session. I was told I would meet a few team members and have a technical session. I took a day off and went there arriving on time.

At the reception I asked for the name I was provided and was told the person who I named I wanted to meet was working from home! I then explained I was there for an interview, I was asked to wait. One developer met me and explained that due to an important meeting no one was available and he would conduct the interview. To me it seemed he had just been handed the job. He seemed pretty smart and we discussed some stuff in the lounge area. I was not invited inside the main office.

Back home I told the agent I felt the company had handled the interview unprofessionally, I would rather they rescheduled if they were going to be very busy. He got back to me saying that they had an audit but were very keen to have me. They suggested another interview where I could get a chance to see their office etc.

Now I am wondering if I should bother. I am very interested in the technology they say they are using, but I feel I can no longer trust them. They didn't seem very organised. Should I simply turn them down or give them yet another chance?

Comment: I'd expect this to be closed because it's not an answerable question.  You're in a much better position to gauge whether you're dealing with a chronically disorganized company or whether you happened to get unlucky where something unexpected happened on the two random days that your interviews were scheduled.  Only you know how strongly you feel about people being organized.  Some industries are obviously prone to more emergencies that derail the day.  Some people are more likely to get sidetracked and forget about other meetings.  Some people  are more "go with the flow" types.

Comment: Sometimes advice is what you need, rather than hard answers. Frankly I was unable to judge if they are disorganised or just really busy. They claim to be growing faster than expected, but at least one guy who was supposed to be interviewing me was comfortably working from home.

Comment: Depending on the organization/ situation, "working from home" may well mean "something blew up at 4am.  I VPN'd in from home to troubleshoot.  I'm still working on it and haven't had time to step away to shower yet let alone to make it to the office".

Comment: Hi James, welcome to The Workplace! Unfortunately your question is not a good fit for our site as it is. [Questions about personal decisions](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2695#2695), such as whether to pursue a particular job, are not likely to be useful to other people. Consider rephrasing to make your question more applicable to a broader audience.

Comment: Is this one of your main job leads or do you have 10s of other prospective job offers/interviews scheduled and need to drop one to lighten the load?

Comment: IF you decide to show up for a follow-up interview with the job, go ahead and ask them about what happened, and whether this is a common occurrence or business as usual.  Put your concerns out on the table and see what they say.  Either they'll explain them to your satisfaction or you will realize that this is not a place you want to work for.  Either way, unless you decide to just drop it now, getting things out into the open is to everyone's advantage.

Answer (score 4):

In chaos, there is opportunity.  However, it has to match your personality type.  If you like the idea of going in somewhere that is so "up in the air" that you can easily carve out your own role, and gain some authority, there is probably a great deal of opportunity here, depending on their financial condition.

If you like a more buttoned-down environment where things are predictable and planned thoroughly, this may not be the environment for you.

I, myself, would like the challenge.  My concern is that they are financially stable enough to keep the team going.  I would get frustrated at a "day-in, day-out" job where everything was nailed down.  However, that's something in my personality.  You have to decide if it's what *YOU* want.  It's exciting, and can be very rewarding, but it's not for everybody.  After all, some people choose to be race car drivers, and some people choose to be actuaries.

Comment: First impressions matter. I would not mind some chaos. How can I find out if they are financially stable?, I have only seen the outside of their rented office space. I feel let down because I was really keen to meet with them.

Comment: Signs of financial stability:

1) There is an operations department separate from development that is actually filling customer orders.

2) Their web page is about what they deliver, today, and not about courting venture capital.

3) Senior management has been at the company at least 3 years.  Your manager and fellow developers at least 2 (on average).

Not saying startups are a bad place, either.  It's all about your risk tolerance.

Comment: Based on the feedback the OP has given, it seems it's time to pull the plug.  You have to know the environment you like to work in and you are not going to be happy somewhere that doesn't gel with you.  IMO it's time to pull the plug on this one.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I simply turn them down or give them yet another chance?

As always - it depends.

If you think this indicates a pervasively disorganized company, and if you don't want to work for such a company, and if you don't need this job badly - then turn them down.

Otherwise, take another shot at it, and look for signs that the company and people are too disorganized for your tastes. Whenever you interview, the hiring company is looking to see if you are a good fit for their position. You should be looking to see if the company is a good fit for you.

Answer (score 0):

Fact: it doesn't hurt to show up for the follow up interview.

It sounds like you already have a stable job and looking for another job. That should afford you the ability to "shop around" and look at your possibly positions more closely.

With that said, the way I see it is that it sounds like a chaotic environment. That may or may not be ideal for you especially if you like consistency. Try to go in for another interview, and ask about what happened in the last two scheduled interviews. Make a joke or something to see how they react to your question. If they get upset or sounds like they actually forgot, then that might be the norm there and I would just pass.